# Changing memory page size

Tags: linux, memory, paging, frames

i was reading there,that the number of virtual memory pages are equal to number of physical memory frames and that the size of frames and that of pages are equal,like for my 32bit system the page size is 4096.

Well i was thinking is there there any way to change the page size or the frame size?

I am using Linux OS. I have searched a lot and what I found is,we can change the page size or in fact we can increase the page size by shifting to huge pages.Is there any other way to change (increase or decrease) or set the page size of our choice?

(Not coding anything,a general question)

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: You should edit your question to improve it (at least, add the `Linux` tag). And please explain why you are asking and what kind of application are you coding!

Comment: I am not coding anything.. its just a general question.. i just wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

In practice it is (nearly) impossible to "change" the memory page size, since the [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_%28computer_memory%29#Page_size_trade-off) size is known & determined by the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) hardware, so the operating system is taking that into account. However, notice that *some* Linux systems (and hardware!) have [**hugetlbpage**](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/hugetlbpage.txt) and Linux [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) might accept `MAP_HUGETLB` (but your code should handle the case of processors or kernels without huge page support, e.g. by calling `mmap` again *without* `MAP_HUGETLB` when the first `mmap` with `MAP_HUGETLB` has failed).

<sup>From what I read, on *some* Linux systems, you can use `hugetlbpage` with various sizes. But the sysadmin can restrict these (or some kernels disable it), so your code should always be prepared that a `mmap` with `MAP_HUGETLB` fails.</sup>

Even with those "huge pages", the page size is *not* arbitrary. Use `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)` on POSIX systems to get the standard page size (it is usually 4Kbytes). See also [sysconf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html)

AFAIK, even on systems with `hugetlbpage` feature, `mmap` can be called *without*  `MAP_HUGETLB` and the page size (as reported by `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`) is still 4Kbytes. Perhaps some recent kernels with some weird configurations are using huge pages everywhere, and IIRC some kernels might be configured with 1Mbyte page (i am not sure about that and I might be wrong)...

Comment: yes it is 4.. i am using linux.. whether its hugepage or simple page,we cannot chnge the SIZE.. i am right?
well in my system,huge-page size is 2048kb.. i can increse the number of huge pages but cannot change the size..

Comment: You can use `mmap` with `MAP_HUGETLB` but you should handle the failure case (e.g. by calling `mmap` again *without* `MAP_HUGETLB`)